# How to assign a member function to an array and call it

Tags: php, function-pointers

I'm currently doing it this way, but seems to not be the proper way:

```
class Name
{
    protected $jobs2do;

    public function __construct($string) {
        $this->jobs2do[] = $this->do;
    }

        public function do() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Because directly assign a function will cause warning, should do something like:

```
function func()
{
...
}

$func_array[] = 'func';
```

say, put it into a string, but I don't know how to do it when it's a member function.

Is the following version OK?:

```
class Name
{
    public $jobs2do;

    public function __construct($string) {
        $this->jobs2do[] = array($this,'do');
    }

        public function do() {
        ...
    }
}
```

when call it, just:

```
$instance = new Name();
foreach ($instance->jobs2do as $job)
{
    call_user_func($job);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a class for Job and use [factory](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php) pattern to create them. Then Write a class JobManager wihich should maintain a list ob Job instances.

```
interface iCallableJob
{
    public function run();
}

class Job implements iCallableJob
{
    // The parameterized factory method
    public static function factory($type)
    {
        $classname = 'Job_' . $type;
        if (class_exists($classname) && in_array('iCallableJob', class_implements('Job')))
        {
            return new $classname();
        }
        return null;
    }
    public function run() { return null; }
}

class Job_type1 extends Job 
{
    public function run() 
    {
        echo 'Job 1';
    }
}

class JobManager
{
    protected $jobs2do = array();

    public function addJob($type)
    {
        if ($job = Job::factory($type))
        {
            $this->jobs2do[] = $job;
            return $job;
        }
        return null;
    }
    public function runAll()
    {
        foreach ($this->jobs2do AS $job)
        {
            $job->run();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) 4 ways to do this. There are other ways but these are the most pure. The method versions require PHP5 at a minimum.

```
class foo {
    public function bar($a) { return $a; }
}

$anObject = new foo();
$ret = call_user_func(array($anObject,'bar'), 1);
$ret = call_user_func_array(array($anObject,'bar'), array(1));
$ret = call_user_method('bar', $anObject, array(1));
$ret = call_user_method_array('bar', $anObjectm, 1);
```

You can replace 'bar' with a string variable, too.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [callable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback) pseudo type. You can then call that function with [call_user_func()](http://www.php.net/call_user_func):

```
class Foo {
    function bar($str) {
        echo($str);
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$func_array = array();
$func_array['foo->bar'] = array($foo, 'bar');  // this is the 'callable' pseudo-type

call_user_func($func_array['foo->bar'], "Hello World");
```

**Edit:** It seems you're trying to implement the [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern). In that case you could try something along these lines:

```
// define an interface for all actions
interface Executable {
    public function do();
}

// an example action
class DoSomething implements Executable {
    private $name;

    public __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function do($str) {
        echo("Hello $str, my name is $this->name");
    }
}

$objects_to_process = array(new DoSomething("Foo"), new DoSomething("Bar"));
foreach ($objects_to_process as $obj) {
    if ($obj instanceof Executable)
        $obj->do("World");
}
```

Comment: But I'm not going to call user function,but a member function:(

Comment: Doesn't matter. Just look at my little example.

Comment: Thank you,I've updated my post,could you tell me if that's right when in a constructor?

Comment: Oh,seems you are using multiple instances,which is different from my design:(

Comment: Okay, I see. Fair enough. Yes, I think your code looks fine then.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [call_user_func()](http://www.php.net/call_user_func) or [call_user_func_array()](http://www.php.net/call_user_func_array)

Answer (score 0):

There can be several possible solutions to this problem. You have Command and Factory patterns presented in other replies. This one illustrates how to use [Visitor](http://dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternVisitor.aspx) + [Command](http://dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternCommand.aspx) pattern cooperation.

```
class Name {

    protected $jobs = array();

    public function addJob(IJob $j) {
        $this->jobs[] = $j;
    }

    public function do() {
        foreach ($this->jobs as $j) {
            $j->run($this);
        }
    }

}

interface IJob {

    public function run(Name $invoker);

}

class WashDishes implements IJob {

    public function run(Name $invoker) {
        echo get_class($invoker) . ' washes dishes<br/>';
    }

}

class DoShopping implements IJob {

    public function run(Name $invoker) {
        echo get_class($invoker) . ' does shopping<br/>';
    }

}

$n = new Name();
$n->addJob(new WashDishes());
$n->addJob(new DoShopping());
$n->do();
```

Output:

```
Name washes dishes
Name does shopping
```

A class implementing `IJob` interface is a command that can be passed and stored for later execution. The way `Name` object invokes jobs in collection (passing `$this` reference) is typical for Visitor pattern (this way job object has access its caller - `Name` object). However, true Visitor pattern is not possible in PHP due to lack of native support for explicit method overriding.

Answer (score 0):

dont know if this is the correct way. but this is how i do mine.

```
$this->api['google']['+1Button']=function($str)
    {
        echo $str;
    };
    $this->api['google']['+1Button']("hello world");
```